# logback.xml from spring-cloud-config server with Vault and git backend

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, hashicorp-vault

I have a config server using git and vault backends and several clients that access the config server, everything is working fine so far. Now I want to centralize the logging configuration as well (as they will all log to logstash) and have added the logback.xml to the repository.

Now I'm faced with a basic problem that has always existed but was never a problem: The config server only accepts requests that have the "X-Config-Token" header, otherwise it just rejects the request. The header value itself doesn't matter, it just has to be present. Is there a way around this limitation? I've put

`logging:
  config: ${spring.cloud.config.uri}/${spring.application.name}/${spring.profiles.active}/master/logback.xml`

in my bootstrap.yml which obviously can't send any headers. It actually baffles me that requests without a token are rejected and that Spring doesn't just serve from git and ignores Vault when no token is present.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug within Spring, see https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1512